# tried to access value in object using the incorrect way

Tags: javascript, arrays

Edit

I tried to access value in object using the incorrect way, I have edited this question to stop others from making the same mistake.

Simply store that object into a variable (something like var obj = {...} and type obj.skills to get the skills array back. If you wanted to get test from the cal_strs array, you can do obj.cal_strs[0].test

```
    <pre>

var obj = 
    {
        "skills": [],
        "languages": [],
        "cal_strs": [{
            "test": null,
            "primary_test": null
        }],
        "id": 123,
        "my_id": 1346,
        "username": "blahblah",
        "full_name": "mr blah",
        "email": "blah@blah.com",
        "location": "boston",
        "manager": "boss",
        "status": 1,
        "abc_status": "here",
        "s_s": "2010-06-08T23:00:00Z",
        "s_e": "2010-06-13T07:00:00Z",
        "n_c": "2010-07-08T07:00:00Z",
        "last_here": null
    }

console.log(obj.location);
console.log(obj.status);

<pre>
```

Comment: Try using jQuery.parseJSON(json). See this [documutation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Comment: use like this `console.log(data.location)
console.log(data.status)
console.log(data.s_s)
console.log(data.s_e)
console.log(data.n_c)`

Comment: If `data` is a string (which it seems to be since `data[0]` gave you the first character, and which you could confirm with `console.log(typeof data)`), then you need to use `JSON.parse(data)`. Using `JSON.stringify(data)` makes no sense here regardless of what format `data` is.

Comment: You're getting the syntax error on `JSON.parse` because it's not json. It's already parsed as a javascript object. Just start navigating it. Since you're getting a character as a return when typing `data[0]`, what you posted is not accurate with what you are actually working with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have here is a object literal, witch can be manipulated without the use of jquery, to read this object you use the dot notation to get the object value based on the key
   `obj.key = value`

```
var obj = 
    {
        "skills": [],
        "languages": [],
        "cal_strs": [{
            "test": null,
            "primary_test": null
        }],
        "id": 123,
        "my_id": 1346,
        "username": "blahblah",
        "full_name": "mr blah",
        "email": "blah@blah.com",
        "location": "boston",
        "manager": "boss",
        "status": 1,
        "abc_status": "here",
        "s_s": "2010-06-08T23:00:00Z",
        "s_e": "2010-06-13T07:00:00Z",
        "n_c": "2010-07-08T07:00:00Z",
        "last_here": null
    }
console.log(obj.location);
console.log(obj.status);

var abc_status = obj.abc_status;//save the value to a variable
```

Comment: What the code in your answer shows is an object created using an object literal. This is *not* JSON, which is a string format used for data interchange.

Comment: `cal_strs` is a array of object,  array are [] and object are {}, so for array you do what you normally do a loop or in your case (since you have only one element in it) you select based on the key which starts at 0 cal_strs[0] wich is = with `{
            "test": null,
            "primary_test": null
        }` now you have a object which you will get values from it with the sintax above `cal_str[0].test`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access your json object as if it's an array. It's not. You can access your objects already since it's already a proper javascript object (it's not json). Simply store that object into a variable (something like `var obj = {...}` and type `obj.skills` to get the skills array back. If you wanted to get `test` from the `cal_strs` array, you can do `obj.cal_strs[0].test`.

Answer (score 0):

Use underscore(_.pluck) get the specific values from the object.
Or try to define a new variable and reassign it .

```
var s =  {
        "skills": [],
        "languages": [],
        "cal_strs": [{
            "test": null,
            "primary_test": null
        }],
        "id": 123,
        "my_id": 1346,
        "username": "blahblah",
        "full_name": "mr blah",
        "email": "blah@blah.com",
        "location": "boston",
        "manager": "boss",
        "status": 1,
        "abc_status": "here",
        "s_s": "2010-06-08T23:00:00Z",
        "s_e": "2010-06-13T07:00:00Z",
        "n_c": "2010-07-08T07:00:00Z",
        "last_here": null,
    }
var t = {};
t['location'] = s.location;
t['status'] = s.status;
t['abc_status'] = s.abc_status;
t['s_s'] = s.s_s;
t['s_e'] = s.s_e;
t['n_c'] = s.n_c;
```

in case multiple arrays use underscore.

Comment: You don't need to use underscore to get values from a javascript object. This is native. No library required

Comment: use for loop condition to get the array values, and get a every values. @mwilson

Comment: There is no need for a for loop here unless OP is wanting to loop through one of the arrays in the js object. I would also be cautious of using a for loop with a javascript object as it may be nested and therefore require recursion or other logic. You could certainly use a `for in` loop to loop through the objects, however.